# conflict between type in lib and .h file in my /usr/include

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile the source code for Unix Network Programming [website here](http://unpbook.com/). While compiling the `libfree` directory of the book's sourcecode, I got this error indicating the there was conflicting types between a function declared in the `inet_top.c` file of the book's library and an `h` file in my `/usr/include/arpa/inet.h` dir/file on my OSX.

I do not know whether the directory/file on my Mac ( i.e.`/usr/include/arpa/inet.h` ) came with the install (which may indicate if I shouldn't delete it) or if it's something that I installed subsequently/after purchase (which might mean I can delete safely) or if there's a way to fix the conflict without deleting. Even though that last sentence doesn't end with a `?`, there is a question in it that I hope can be answered.

```
gcc -I../lib -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall   -c -o inet_ntop.o inet_ntop.c
inet_ntop.c:56:1: error: conflicting types for 'inet_ntop'
inet_ntop(af, src, dst, size)
^
/usr/include/arpa/inet.h:77:13: note: previous declaration is here
const char      *inet_ntop(int, const void *, char *, socklen_t);
                 ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [inet_ntop.o] Error 1
```

Comment: How is the header file included? Show that part of the code. Try to include it with double quotes and the proper path instead of angular brackets (you may need to leave out the `-I` option in the compilation then); that should pick up the local header file.

Comment: Looks like a conflict of  return types for the function **inet_ntop()** This can cause fatal errors, which is why the linker won't allow it.

Comment: I would say the book example is either out of date, not trying to be posix compliant or just wrong. The include file has the correct definition of the function [as defined by posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't want to delete the header in `/usr...`, it's part of the system headers. It is better to fix the source from the book.  In fact, since I'm also on a Mac, I quickly downloaded the source and tried it.  Ran into the error.  The problem is the 4th parameter: it is of type `size_t` in the book source, but the header has it as `socklen_t`.  So, edit `inet_ntop` as follows:

```
...
const char *
inet_ntop(af, src, dst, size)
        int af;
        const void *src;
        char *dst;
        socklen_t size;  /* socklen_t was size_t originally */
{
        switch (af) {
...
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Trying it on a CentOS 7 box, I got the same error.  The same fix worked there as well.  It looks like the code from the book is fairly old, so some APIs may have slightly changed.

Comment: thank you I will try this out and get back to you to accept your answer. so is everything in /usr/include standard lib? The /arpa/ dir sounded like some sort of proprietary name to me.

Comment: ARPA stands for (DoD) Advanced Research Projects Agency.   That's where Internet technologies originated from a few decades ago.  The `arpa` directory is part of the C networking APIs on a typical UNIX-like system, including Mac OS X.   And yes, `/usr/include` is where important system headers normally live.

Answer (score 1):

Code in UNP is too old that standard library has changed but UNP's code still using the old one. So you just modify `inet_ntop` in UNP to fit standard lib `/usr/include/arpa/inet.h`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling for Windows™ use that version,

If you are compiling for iOS use that definition of **inet_ntop()**